# Trying to get React Three Drei Loader component to load before the rest of my site,

Tags: reactjs, vite, react-three-drei

I can't seem to get the Loader component to load before anything else. My site initializes, and then pops to the loader instead of hitting the loader first so it seems a little jarring.

```
import react from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { About, Contact, Experience, Navbar,Hero, Tech, Works, StarsCanvas } from './components';
import { Loader } from '@react-three/drei'
import './styles/index.css'


const App = () => {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Loader />
      <div className="relative z-0 bg-primary">
       <div className = "bg-hero-pattern bg-cover bg-no-repeat bg-center">
        <Navbar />
        <Home />            
        </div>
       <About />
       <Experience />
       <Tech />
       <Works />
      <div className="relative z-0">
       <Contact />
       <StarsCanvas />
      </div>
    </div>
       </BrowserRouter>
  )
}

export default App
```

I've tried putting the loader in both the canvas component and on the main app.jsx and the result is the same.